# Translate datetimepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I need to use a datepicker with the ability to choose the hours, so I installed an Angular component. I installed this component : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

This component is in english but I will translate it into french...

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                        <dl-date-time-picker
                            startView="day"
                            maxView="year"
                            minView="minute"
                            minuteStep="5"
                            [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
                        >
                        </dl-date-time-picker>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you used angular material in your application?

Comment: @MohitSaxena Yes of course, thansk for your reply

Comment: So If you use datepicker of angular material , are U able to change into French?.

Answer (score 0):

dl-date-time-picker uses moment for translation and formatting.

To translate to french, include `moment/locale/fr.js` in your project and them call `moment.locale('fr');` early in your application.

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/ and https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#display-of-year-month-day-hour-ampm-and-minute-formats for more information